# IdentityServer4 returning 404 Status Code for Every Endpoint

Tags: identityserver4

I've been evaluating IdentityServer as we are looking to use it at work. Whilst it is easy to get running using Visual Studio in a Dev environment, I've never been able to get it running as a deployment on my home server (Windows 2019 Server).

I've got other simple ASP.NET sites running on that server, so I've demonstrated that IIS is working and sites can be served.

When I try to load the MVC UI Quickstart (deployed), I just get a 404 response. I get this for any end-point e.g. `.well-known/openid-configuration`

I've been having a lot of trouble figuring out what's wrong, as the IIS logs have not revealed anything instructive.

I'm just using a self-signed certificate for SSL for the site.
I created a pfx for the Signing Credential using OpenSSL. This works fine in a dev environment. I'm loading it from a specific directory (to which IIS_IUSRS have permission).

Here's my Configuration methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(@"E:\Certs\id4.pfx"), "opensesame"))
        .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList())
        .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources());   

  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

and:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    }

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

**Other Info**
The Windows Hosting bundle is installed (I've got other Core 2.2 apps running on it).
The App Pool is running with `No Managed Code` as the .NET CLR Version. `Enable 32-bit Applications` is set to False.
The Site itself has default settings. `Anonymous` and `Basic Authentication` are enabled.
It has both a http binding for port 80 and an https binding for port 443.

The Web.config, generated by the publish, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SimpleIdp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 6418350e-fa8e-4ac9-9201-f4ba2a4a6abf-->
```

I've had a couple of chops at this over the last few months and always end up in the same place. So it would be great if someone is able to help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provided details of your IIS config, web.config file and whether you have the Windows hosting bundle installed please?

Comment: @mackie I have updated the question (at the end) with info which you requested. Let me know if you would like screen shots of the App Pool and IIS Site configs. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see anything in the stdout log file?

Comment: Check the idsrv4 logs (configure logging first if you haven’t)

Comment: Thanks all. Enabling the logging helped (as you would expect). I'm now loading most endpoint OK in the browser (e.g. login etc). The problem remaining is the loading of the pfx. It works if I deploy with the dev credential, but not with the one I created. That's probably the subject for another question. But I'll try a few things to get that working before I look at seeking further help. I might add the cert to a Store and read it in from there. Cheers and feel free to add an answer which I can mark as so.